# Memory demand increases when running for loop

Tags: macos, swift, for-loop, memory

I try to generate jpeg files from pdf pages with the code below.
The memory demand of this app increases with each iteration but Instruments does not show any leaks.
It seems memory is released only when the for-loop is done, so with a 1000-page pdf the app consumes all memory and the system starts to use virtual memory.
Any hints someone?

```
let pdf = PDFDocument(URL: sourceURL)
var thumbImageURL:NSURL
var pdfImage:NSImage
let thumbRect = NSMakeRect(0.0, 0.0, ceil(CGFloat(Float(pdf.pageAtIndex(0).boundsForBox(kPDFDisplayBoxMediaBox).width) * self.thumbHeight / Float(pdf.pageAtIndex(0).boundsForBox(kPDFDisplayBoxMediaBox).height))), CGFloat(self.thumbHeight))
let rep = NSBitmapImageRep.init(bitmapDataPlanes: nil, pixelsWide: Int(thumbRect.width), pixelsHigh: Int(thumbRect.height), bitsPerSample: 8, samplesPerPixel: 4, hasAlpha: true, isPlanar: false, colorSpaceName: NSCalibratedRGBColorSpace, bytesPerRow: 0, bitsPerPixel: 0)!               
NSGraphicsContext.saveGraphicsState()
let myContext = NSGraphicsContext.init(bitmapImageRep: rep)
NSGraphicsContext.setCurrentContext(myContext)
var jpegImage:NSData
       for i in 0 ..< pdf.pageCount(){

            thumbImageURL = self.targetURL!.URLByAppendingPathComponent("/pages/\(i+1)-thumb.jpg")
            pdfImage = NSImage.init(data: pdf.pageAtIndex(i).dataRepresentation())!
            pdfImage.drawInRect(thumbRect, fromRect: NSZeroRect, operation: NSCompositingOperation.CompositeCopy, fraction: 1.0)
            jpegImage = rep.representationUsingType(NSBitmapImageFileType.NSJPEGFileType, properties: [:])!
            jpegImage.writeToURL(thumbImageURL, atomically: false)
        }
            NSGraphicsContext.restoreGraphicsState()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to create a autorelease pool block for the loop, this mechanism can reduce peak memory footprint:

> https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmAutoreleasePools.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000047-CJBFBEDI

To do that you have to wrap the code inside the loop like that:

```
for i in 0 ..< pdf.pageCount(){    
    autoreleasepool {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, thats it!
(I did not know that Swift also has the autoreleasepool statement as in Objective-C)